# I want to convert 1 minute olhc intraday stock data (present in pandas dataframe) into higher timeframe olhc data like 5min,10min,15min olhc data

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have 1 minute timeframe olhc candle data of intraday stock (in pandas dataframe) .
I want to convert 1 minute olhc intraday stock data (present in pandas dataframe)  into higher timeframe olhc data like 5min,10min,15min olhc data .

```
     open     low    high   close  volume Adj_Close
2020-07-24 13:12:00  191.00  190.95  191.00  190.95   21131    190.95
2020-07-24 13:11:00  190.80  190.80  190.95  190.85   88030    190.85
2020-07-24 13:10:00  191.25  190.80  191.25  190.80  163046    190.80
2020-07-24 13:09:00  191.15  191.15  191.20  191.20   71910    191.20
2020-07-24 13:08:00  191.10  191.05  191.20  191.10  100514    191.10
...                     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...       ...
2020-07-23 12:51:00  194.90  194.75  194.90  194.75   44430    194.75
2020-07-23 12:50:00  194.85  194.75  194.85  194.85  116263    194.85
2020-07-23 12:49:00  194.85  194.85  194.95  194.95   34569    194.95
2020-07-23 12:48:00  194.70  194.70  194.85  194.85  154293    194.85
2020-07-23 12:47:00  194.95  194.80  194.95  194.80  145786    194.80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `agg()` function lets you pass in a dictionary of functions, for column-specific aggregations.  We will create two dictionaries:  one for aggregation logic, and the other to rename columns:

```
def resample_stock_data(df, timedelta):
    # make a copy
    df = df.copy()

    # convert index to datetime
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

    # sort the index (evidently required by resample())
    df = df.sort_index()

    aggregation_dict = {
        'volume': 'mean', 
         'open': 'sum', 
         'high': 'sum',
         'low': 'sum',
         'close': 'sum',
         'Adj_Close': 'sum'
    }

    rename_dict = {
        'open': 'first',
        'high': 'max_price',
        'low': 'min_price',
        'close': 'last_price',
        'volume': 'vol (shares)',
        'Adj_Close': 'last',
    }


    return (df
      .resample(timedelta)
      .agg(aggregation_dict)
      .rename(columns=rename_dict)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing the information on what should be used as the aggregating function. In my answer, I am assuming that you wanted to take the **sum** of `volume` and **mean** of the other columns.
You can use [df.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample). You need to have a dataframe with a datetime index. That means using datetime objects instead of multi-level strings as the index of the dataframe. This is generally a good idea for timeseries data.
Once you have the datetime index, you simply need to call the `resample` method of the dataframe and say how you want to aggregate the data.

```
def resample_stock_data(df, timedelta):
    """Resample stock data to a timedelta.
    
    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): DataFrame of stock data to resample
        timedelta: DateOffset, TimeDelta or str to resample to.
    Returns:
        pd.DataFrame: Resampled dataframe"""
        
    # Create a datetime index
    df = df.reset_index()
    df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['level_0'] + ' ' + df['level_1']))
    df = df.drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], axis=1)
    # Resample data
    olhc = df.drop('volume', axis=1)
    olhc = olhc.resample(timedelta).mean()
    volume = df['volume']
    volume = volume.resample(timedelta).sum()
    resampled = pd.concat([olhc, volume], axis=1)
    return resampled

resampled_05m = resample_stock_data(df, '5min')
resampled_10m = resample_stock_data(df, '10min')
resampled_15m = resample_stock_data(df, '15min')
```

Comment: sorry for not mentioning the information on  what should be used the aggregate function. actually i want like for 5min ohlc data the 5 continuous rows of 1min candle is taken and then the high is the highest of those 5high, low is the lowest of lows. open is the open of starting minute row. close is the close of the last row . and volume is the sum of all the volumes of all 5 candles. like below code

Comment: # df1 = df.resample('h').agg({
                #                             'open': lambda s: s[0],
                #                             'high': lambda df: df.max(),
                #                             'low': lambda df: df.min(),
                #                             'close': lambda df: df[-1],
                #                             'volume': lambda df: df.sum()})
                # print(df1)

Comment: @sonu bluestack:  I created separate dictionaries for aggregation and for renaming.  Does this address your question?  (Sorry if I mis-understood.)